# Spring can no longer identify unique bean by name in Java-13

Tags: java, spring

Consider the following example:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SuppressWarnings("all")
@Configuration
public class SpringJava13 {

    @Bean
    public SpringJava13 spj13(String foo) {
        return new SpringJava13();
    }

    @Bean
    public String foo() {
        return "Foomatic";
    }

    @Bean
    public String bar() {
        return "Barrista";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringJava13.class);
        SpringJava13 bean = (SpringJava13) ctx.getBean("spj13");
        System.out.println("Bean created.");
    }
}
```

Up to Java-12 this runs fine, because the spj13-bean requires a unique String-Bean. We have two String beans available and one of them matches the parameter Name ("foo"). All is well.

If I run the above example in Java-13, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'spj13' defined in prv.rli.codetest.SpringJava13: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'spj13' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: foo,bar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:88)
    at prv.rli.codetest.SpringJava13.main(SpringJava13.java:27)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: foo,bar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 14 more
```

Spring seems to no longer be able to identify the unique bean.

Versions involved:

- AdoptOpenJDK (build 13.0.1+9) running on Linux.
- Spring: 5.1.5

What is the reason for such a behaviour change?

Update: The problem goes away with Spring-5.2.1, but I still find it puzzling that such a problem can arise from a change in the JDK version.

Comment: Use @Value annotation above the method declaration and pass a value to it

Comment: Also, according to the Spring version ranges, 5.1.5 has only been tested on Java 8 - 12. You would have to upgrade to 5.2.x for it to have been tested on Java 13.

Comment: I had the version lying around, so maybe this is helpful: I couldn't reproduce it with Spring `4.3.18.RELEASE`